# Can I print a list of acronyms without a header with the acro package?

Tags: sectioning, acronyms

I want to produce a list of acronyms from the `acro` package without any header at all. Is this possible? I have tried putting things like `*`, `{}`, and `(space)` in the header argument, but nothing has worked. The best I can do is use `header=subsection*` and leave `name=` but this still leaves whitespace where the subsection title *should* be.

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{SAE}{
short=SAE,
long=Stackexchange acronym example}

\begin{document}
Here's a \ac{SAE}
\printacronyms[header=subsection*, name=]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can declare an `empty` instance for the `heading` key (`header` is deprecated as **Harish Kumar** pointed out):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareInstance{acro-title}{empty}{sectioning}{name-format =}

\DeclareAcronym{SAE}{
short=SAE,
long=Stackexchange acronym example}

\begin{document}
Here's a \ac{SAE}
\printacronyms[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar ah, thank you for pointing that out! (I should pay more attention to console messages).

Comment: Huh, I have no idea what your code means/does, but it works.


For some reason my `acro` won't work with `heading`, but `header=empty` did just what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @DocBuckets using the `xtemplate` parlance, my code creates the instance `empty` (which suppresses the heading) for the template `sectioning` corresponding to the object type `acro-title`; the instance simply sets the `name-format` key to do nothing.

Comment: @DocBuckets `header` was recently declared deprecated (in `acro` version 1.3 from 2013/05/06). Perhaps you are using an older version, so you need to use `header`.

Comment: Yep, I was on 1.2. It's been a while since I've run at MiKTeX update. Thanks for the answer and additional help

Comment: You don't need `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` if you kill the whitespace in the first three arguments of `\DeclareInstance`

Comment: Only "\printacronyms[heading=none]" works without using \DeclareInstance